# Laravel 5.3 application throws error instead of displaying login view

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I am working on a Laravel application. I am trying to access a local dev version of the application using the following address:

http://localhost/~john.doe/myapplication/public

Upon browsing to this address, I get redirected to the /login route of the application - which is what should happen. However, I get an exception error on the page;

```
ErrorException in 06a6f15f043ca181cc57503568e1dfcf221e98e8.php line 67: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/john.doe/Sites/myapplication/resources/views/app.blade.php)
```

The line in question has the following snippet (which is causing the error):

```
Auth::user()->site_skin
```

The user has not logged in so Auth::user() is null.

Why is the view file app.blade.php being loaded? For the login route, the login.blade.php should be loaded. I have a feeling it is to do with the address I am using to access the website. I was previously using a localhost alias but this does not work anymore (work firewall issues) therefore I am using the `http://localhost/~john.doe/myapplication/public` address.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: if a user is not logged in or authenticated you cant get any data out of the Auth::user() so do try to login a user and try again

Comment: Does your `login.blade.php` extend `app`?

Comment: @spartyboy Login route throws that error.

Comment: @Paras Nope, login.blade.php does not extend app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by adding the following in the virtualhosts config block for the application:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Previously, I just had `AllowOverride all`

Answer (score 0):

try `php artisan cache:clear`and`php artisan view:clear` in your project command line

Comment: Can you [edit] the answer and add information about why you think this will solve the question?